# Format Linux partition USB SD

Tags: usb, partition, unix, sd-card

I have a Transcend SD Card 256GB

I was installing CentOS in one partition of my SD Card, testing the OS in my MacBook Air.

Now I can't remove the partition and restore my SD.

[image]

```
sh-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 7887C476-CBE0-4D10-B95A-5C79F83B20D7
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.4 GB    disk2

/dev/disk3 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *259.7 GB   disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data ExFAT                   99.5 GB    disk3s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data W                       84.9 GB    disk3s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data DEL                     1.1 GB     disk3s4
   5:                  Linux LVM                         73.9 GB    disk3s5

/dev/disk4 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *7.5 GB     disk4
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk4s1
   2:               Windows_NTFS Untitled0               7.5 GB     disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *44.6 GB    disk5
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk5s1
   2:               Windows_NTFS Untitled1               44.6 GB    disk5s2

/dev/disk6 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *21.8 GB    disk6
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk6s1
   2:               Windows_NTFS Untitled2               21.8 GB    disk6s2

/dev/disk7 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk7
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk7s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HD710A                  999.9 GB   disk7s2

sh-3.2#
```

I have problem with:

```
5:                  Linux LVM                         73.9 GB    disk3s5
```

I'm using **macOS Sierra 10.12.6**

I got:

```
sh-3.2# sudo diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ ExLinux disk3s5
Started erase on disk3s5
Unmounting disk
Error: -69879: Couldn't open disk
sh-3.2#
```

Comment: Can you please tell us the output of `diskutil list`?

Comment: And what version of macOS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This will erase the partition to make it visible in Disk Utility(change PartitionName to whatever you want and see below to get DiskIdentifier):

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ PartitionName DiskIdentifier
```

To get DiskIdentifier, Run `diskutil list` and find the partition you want to remove. DiskIdentifier is in the `IDENTIFIER` column.

Now you should be able to remove the partition in Disk Utility like normal.

Comment: Executing the command given in your answer does not guarantee you will be able to remove the partition using the Disk Utility.